Moving Woocommerce category title and description after main content
I'm using code snippets to try move the Woocommerce category title and description after main content. I found this simple code:
// remove woocommerce category description
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 ); 

// add woocommerce category description
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );

This did not work, I believe because my theme is overriding the default woocommerce code. The theme's settings are as follows:
<?php

    // declare woocommerce support
    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'kleanity_woocommerce_support');
    if( !function_exists( 'kleanity_woocommerce_support' ) ){
        function kleanity_woocommerce_support(){
            add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
            add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
            add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
            add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
        }
    }   

    // modify woocommerce wrapper
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

    add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'kleanity_woocommerce_wrapper_start', 10);
    if( !function_exists( 'kleanity_woocommerce_wrapper_start' ) ){
        function kleanity_woocommerce_wrapper_start(){
            echo '<div class="kleanity-content-container kleanity-container">';
            echo '<div class="kleanity-content-area kleanity-item-pdlr kleanity-sidebar-style-none clearfix" >';
        }
    }

    add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'kleanity_woocomemrce_wrapper_end', 10);
    if( !function_exists( 'kleanity_woocomemrce_wrapper_end' ) ){
        function kleanity_woocomemrce_wrapper_end(){
            echo '</div>'; // kleanity-content-area
            echo '</div>'; // kleanity-content-container
        }
    }

    // remove breadcrumbs on single product
    add_action('wp', 'kleanity_init_woocommerce_hook');
    if( !function_exists( 'kleanity_init_woocommerce_hook' ) ){
        function kleanity_init_woocommerce_hook(){
            if( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'product' ){ 
                add_filter('woocommerce_product_description_heading', 'kleanity_remove_woocommerce_tab_heading');
                add_filter('woocommerce_product_additional_information_heading', 'kleanity_remove_woocommerce_tab_heading');

                remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20);
                remove_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash', 10);
                remove_action('woocommerce_review_before_comment_meta', 'woocommerce_review_display_rating', 10);

                add_action('woocommerce_review_after_comment_text', 'woocommerce_review_display_rating', 10);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if( !function_exists( 'kleanity_remove_woocommerce_tab_heading' ) ){
        function kleanity_remove_woocommerce_tab_heading( $title ){
            return '';
        }
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_review_gravatar_size', 'kleanity_woocommerce_review_gravatar_size');
    if( !function_exists( 'kleanity_woocommerce_review_gravatar_size' ) ){
        function kleanity_woocommerce_review_gravatar_size( $size ){
            return 120;
        }
    }

    if( !function_exists('kleanity_get_woocommerce_bar') ){
        function kleanity_get_woocommerce_bar(){

            global $woocommerce;
            
            if(!empty($woocommerce)){
                
                echo '<span class="kleanity-top-cart-count">' . $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count . '</span>';
                echo '<div class="kleanity-top-cart-hover-area" ></div>';

                echo '<div class="kleanity-top-cart-content-wrap" >';
                echo '<div class="kleanity-top-cart-content" >';
                echo '<div class="kleanity-top-cart-count-wrap" >';
                echo '<span class="head">' . esc_html__('Items : ', 'kleanity') . ' </span>';
                echo '<span class="kleanity-top-cart-count">' . $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count . '</span>'; 
                echo '</div>';
                
                echo '<div class="kleanity-top-cart-amount-wrap" >';
                echo '<span class="head">' . esc_html__('Subtotal :', 'kleanity') . ' </span>';
                echo '<span class="kleanity-top-cart-amount">' . $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() . '</span>';
                echo '</div>';
                
                echo '<a class="kleanity-top-cart-button" href="' . esc_url($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url()) . '" >';
                echo esc_html__('View Cart', 'kleanity');
                echo '</a>';

                echo '<a class="kleanity-top-cart-checkout-button" href="' . esc_url($woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url()) . '" >';
                echo esc_html__('Check Out', 'kleanity');
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'gdlr_woocommerce_cart_ajax');
    if( !function_exists('gdlr_woocommerce_cart_ajax') ){
        function gdlr_woocommerce_cart_ajax($fragments){
            global $woocommerce;

            $fragments['span.kleanity-top-cart-count'] = '<span class="kleanity-top-cart-count">' . $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count . '</span>'; 
            $fragments['span.kleanity-top-cart-amount'] = '<span class="kleanity-top-cart-amount">' . $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() . '</span>';

            return $fragments;
        }
    }   

    add_filter('woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'kleanity_related_products_args');
    if( !function_exists('kleanity_related_products_args') ){
        function kleanity_related_products_args($args){
            if( class_exists('gdlr_core_pb_element_product') ){
                $num_fetch = kleanity_get_option('general', 'woocommerce-related-product-num-fetch', '4');
                $args['posts_per_page'] = $num_fetch;
            }
            
            return $args;
        }
    }

So I then tried the following to achieve the result:
// remove woocommerce category description
remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 20);

// add woocommerce category description after
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'kleanity_after_main_content_taxonomy_archive_description', 5);

function kleanity_after_main_content_taxonomy_archive_description() {
    // Check if this is a product category archive page
    if (is_product_category()) {
        // Get the category description
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $description = $term->description;

        // write category description HTML
        if (!empty($description)) {
            echo '<div class="kleanity-archive-taxonomy-description kleanity-item-pdlr">';
            echo wpautop(wptexturize($description));
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}

Still no joy. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance
